# AMP - Initial sorting with amp-sort

Tags: amp-html

How can I make my list be initially sorted when the page loads?

Referring to https://dereklewis.github.io/amp-docs/docs/reference/components/amp-sort/ I was playing with this list:

```
Green Hoodie - $20
Red Shirt - $30
Blue T-Shirt - $10
White T-Shirt - $17.50
```

This is the source code

```html
<amp-sort id="priceSorter"
  sort-by="data-price"
  sort-direction="desc"
  value-type="number">
  <button on="tap:priceSorter.sort();">Sort by price: highest first</button>
  <ul>
    <li data-price="20">Green Hoodie - $20</li>
    <li data-price="30">Red Shirt - $30</li>
    <li data-price="10">Blue T-Shirt - $10</li>
    <li data-price="17.5">White T-Shirt - $17.50</li>
  </ul>
</amp-sort>
```

I cannot use custom JavaScript, since this is AMP.
What should I set up, so that this list will be sorted on page load, and NOT on click?

Answer (score 0):

The AMP team decided to not implement `amp-sort`:

> No longer planning to launch this component since the use-case can be
>   handle via amp-list, amp-state and amp-bind. Please see
>   https://ampbyexample.com/samples_templates/product_browse_page/

https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/8691#issuecomment-431446158

In your case it means that the data endpoint used by your amp-list needs to initially return the elements in the correct order.